# UWP Navigate to same Page

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, windows-10-universal

I have a Page *(showDocuments)* that shows documents and folders (like in Dropbox or Google Drive). When a user clicks on a folder I'm trying to navigate to a new instance of the *showDocuments* Page in order to show the content of the clicked folder. However, when I render the new information, it appears both the new documents and the previous ones.

I could do it by just having one page and cleaning it each time, but I need different pages in order to go back to the parent folders using frame.GoBack(), since it is much faster rather than using frame.Navigate(...) and compute and print everything again.

I'm not using a MVVM model, I just have a page and I decide which objects I need to show on the xaml.cs file.

Should I use views instead of pages?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Pls show what you allready tried (code)

Comment: What do you mean by "However, when I render the new information, it appears both the new documents and the previous ones."? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: I mean that it prints the documents (data) that I had on the previous page, and the documents that are supposed to be printed on the new "instance"of the same page. @AndrewBares

Answer (score 0):

Try by handle the back button operation to catch parameters and navigating back.
You could have global vars of parent folder: the **value** (parentFolderVar) you pass to *showDocuments* Page and **isReturn** that is setted in OnNavigatedTo Method:

```
App.parentFolderVar = someValue;
```

So, when you handle tha back operation in App.xaml.cs:

```
private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if (rootFrame.SourcePageType == typeof(showDocuments))
        App.isReturn = true;
    e.Handled = true;
    Pause();
}
```

And in showDocuments navigation:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if(App.isReturn)
        //You know the parent folder with App.parentFolderVar
    //Make operations
    App.parentFolderVar  = updatedParentFolderValue;
    App.isReturn = false;
}
```